# "Variable is used before initialized" when @Environment(\.dismiss) is used

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to have a very simple SwiftUI view hierarchy:
parent and a child.
The child should be able to dismiss itself with a tap of a button.

The following code **works fine**

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink {
                ChildView()
            } label: {
                Text("Go")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
        Button(action: {
            dismiss()
        }, label: {
            Text("Dismiss")
        })
    }
}
```

However, when I try to add a simple state and `init()` to the ChildView, I'm hitting a compilation error

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink {
                ChildView(foo: 42)
            } label: {
                Text("Go")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @State private var myInt: Int
    
    init(foo: Int) {
        self.myInt = foo // <--- ERROR IS HERE, "Variable 'self.myInt' used before being initialized"
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, world!")
            .padding()
        Button(action: {
            dismiss()
        }, label: {
            Text("Dismiss")
        })
    }
}
```

This error is very puzzling. I tried different things and as far as I can tell, the problem is in the combination of `init()` and `@Environment(\.dismiss)` presents.
But I really need to have them both for the real project.

Anybody knows what's the reason for the error or how to fix it?

Xcode version: 13.4.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `@State` var has to be initialised differently:

```
self._myInt = State(initialValue: foo)
```

Comment: Nice! Do you know why I can use just `self.myInt = foo` unless `@Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss` line is present?

Comment: It's quite interesting that the code without the environment var does compile and run. Nevertheless your direct init on `myInt` doesn't change its value (I just checked by showing it in the ChildView). The reason it does compile seems to be in the way @State is implemented. Read here under "non mutating" for a deeper explanation: https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/mutating-and-nonmutating-swift-contexts/

Comment: Would like to know the answer to this as well. Best guess is that its dismissing the view itself but not any of those @state variable references. Therefore dismissal in this case requires those references to be defined?